# Overriding Datatable search

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

how to change search text before searching data in `Datatables` ?

for example if user typed `TEXT` in search box , `EDITED_TEXT` will be searched .

I tried these links but none of them solved my problem .

https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching

https://datatables.net/reference/event/search

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any text to the search, or modify text from an input any way you like.  For example:

```
function datatableSearch() {
    var table = $("#example").DataTable();
    var originalSearchText = $("#myInput").val();
    var modifiedSearchText = originalSearchText.replace(".", " ");
    //Do anything you want with the search text here
    table.search(modifiedSearchText).draw();
}
```

You might find more relevant information with a search related to modifying text/strings with JavaScript.

Comment: your answer is suitable when you have created input tag for search .  i want an event for datatable self search input . i dont have any ID or classname for that input

Comment: You can either add an event listener to change the search string (use the key event and reference the generated input -- $("#myTable input[type=search"), or you can removed the generated input and add your own (removed the f from the dom configuration).